# Read C-formatted hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: numerics, data, data-format

I have a lot of 32-bit numbers in hexadecimal symbolized as they are in C (for example, 0x1230abde). How can easily read these in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
data = {"0x1", "0xff", "0x1230abde"};
FromDigits[StringTrim[#, "0x"], 16] & /@ data

{1, 255, 305179614}
```

Comment: I was hoping there might be built-in functionality, but I guess manual string manipulation is the only way to do it.